# Running a shell script from Swift/MacOS

Tags: swift, macos, shell

I've been able to successfully run shell scripts in the past using this function:

```
typealias runShellClosure = (_ jsonString:String) -> Void

func runShell(_ command: String, completion: runShellClosure) {
        let task = Process()
        task.launchPath = "/bin/zsh"
        task.arguments = ["-c", command]

        let pipe = Pipe()
        task.standardOutput = pipe
        task.launch()

        let data = pipe.fileHandleForReading.readDataToEndOfFile()
        let output: String = NSString(data: data, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)! as String

        completion(output)
    }
```

today I installed YQ (using Homebrew) - YQ converts YAML files to JSON.

Ran a test in Terminal:

```
yq r -j ~/Desktop/xxxxxxx/swagger/yml/up-api.yaml
```

and received the expected results. In my app, I am passing the same command to the runShell function:

I get a `command not found` error.

Not sure what I am doing wrong. I just switched to Catalina, but switching the shell back to Bash returned the same results.

Thanks

Edit: I can run this command:

`ls ~/Desktop/Xandr/swagger/yml/`

and get expected results. Also, sandboxing is disabled.

Comment: Y'know, there [*are* YAML parsers available for Swift](https://github.com/jpsim/Yams). I wouldn't advise using an external tool (especially an external tool that isn't provided by your OS vendor) unless you have no other choice.

Comment: ...anyhow, a good place to start would be to start your command with something like `set -x; declare -p PATH` (if the shell is bash). Look at what the PATH it shows is, and look at where your `yq` executable is installed.

Comment: Once again -- check the PATH *inside the environment where your Swift application is running the command*, not in your enclosing shell.

Comment: I've looked at a Swift YML convertor and when I added the pod and built the app it had a ton of errors in the code. Can't remember the name off the top of my head. If you've got a recommendation please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

### Solution 1

Edit Scheme > Arguments > Environment Variables : Add `PATH` and set its value to `${PATH}`

### Solution 2

I was able to execute a homebrew package executable by launching the Command Line Tool target with this option (Edit Scheme > Run > Options):

[image: Screenshot]

The only downside of this solution is that running it from the terminal is very buggy from my experience. It adds a new terminal window everytime you launch it, and it doesn't work if you already have one opened..